# ios: in-app purchase coding best practice to manage the changing of UIViewController

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

i would like to understand what is the coding best practice regarding the in-app purchase.
I am developing an in app where the user can buy non-consumable items (with a restore purchases function).
When the user try to buy or restore a purchase, he will still have the option to move into the app sections (that will also mean a change of the current `UIViewController`).
What is the correct way to manage this situation?
Should I write a singleton object (like `MyStoreKitManager`) to manage it?

Comment: I don't think there're any guidelines for this scenario so it must depend on amount of efforts you can spend.

Comment: Thank you A-Live, but I would like to understand the right solution for that. I am sure there is a correct approach to use: I would like to understand how someone else solved this scenario.

Comment: I was doing purchases with a `purchases-manager` singleton (`<SKProductsRequestDelegate>`) which created `<SKPaymentTransactionObserver>` to track the transactions status. I also created another singleton to control the `purchases-manager` being its delegate, you might want to use notifications instead.